# Approximating the warmest time of day

Tags: thermal-radiation, earth, geophysics, weather

I'm trying to find a very simple approximation of when the maximum air temperature will occur on a given day at a given location.  By "air temperature," I just mean the air temperature at the ground level that a human would experience when walking outside.

We can start with all of the usual simplifying assumptions.  The region is flat.  There are no clouds.  There is no wind.  ​The ground behaves like a blackbody.  I will make the assumption that the ground temperature and the air temperature near the ground are the same, although I don't know whether this is actually true.

I imagine that even with these simplifying assumptions, the energy flows can be quite complex.  But I guess that they are dominated by incoming solar radiation and outgoing blackbody radiation.  The power flux from solar radiation is $S \cos \theta$, where $S \approx 1.3~\text{kW}/\text{m}^2$ and $\theta$ is the angle from a ray going straight upward to the sun.  The temperature outside in the evenings where I live at this time of year is usually around $T=280~\text{K}$, and the outgoing blackbody radiation is $\sigma T^4$ with $\sigma \approx 5.7 \cdot 10^{-8}~\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}^2~\text{K}^4}$.  Setting these equal gives us

$$ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sigma T^4}{S} \right) \approx 74^\circ$$

This seems like a fairly reasonable answer, i.e., when the sun is about $16^\circ$ from the horizon, the energy balance shifts from positive to negative and the local temperature starts to decrease.  But there are some very important parts of the story that I am leaving out.  The biggest one is the atmosphere, which I have essentially ignored entirely.

This article on [Earth's energy budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_energy_budget) makes it clear that there are other very significant factors that I'm ignoring, such as:

- A lot of solar radiation is immediately reflected back into space.
- The atmosphere reflects back a lot of Earth's blackbody radiation.

Another issue, not discussed on the article (which focuses on the entire Earth), is:

- A lot of energy is probably absorbed by the atmosphere rather than reaching the ground (or the air immediately above the ground).

So here are my questions:

- How important are the effects I listed above?
- If they are important, is there an easy heuristic to use in my estimate?
- Are there any other important effects that I didn't list above?

If this is relevant, my background is in physics and nonlinear dynamics, but (as the question probably makes clear) I have no knowledge of geophysics, weather modeling, climate modeling, or other fields that would be relevant here.